# How to know if a record has updated its date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I want to know if a record has update its date in a pandas Dataframe. The dataframe is made up of several columns in which for each value of A we have several values ​​of B with start dates and end dates. Thanks to the timestamp we can know if there is a new record or a previous one has been modified.

What I want to know is how to be able to check if a new record has a date range close to other records in its group, for example B1 group and if they have a similar date range, delete the previous one and only leave the new record updated, but if it doesn't have a common range to interpret as a new record.

For example,

Input Dataframe:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 2021-05-27 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-04-15 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 2021-05-12 00:00:00 | 2021-03-15 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 2021-02-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-07-15 00:00:00 | 2021-08-15 00:00:00 | 2021-04-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-17 00:00:00 | 2021-04-15 00:00:00 |

Expected Output:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-05-10 00:00:00 | 2021-05-27 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2021-06-04 00:00:00 | 2021-02-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B3 | 2021-07-15 00:00:00 | 2021-08-15 00:00:00 | 2021-04-15 00:00:00 |
| A2 | B4 | 2021-05-30 00:00:00 | 2021-06-15 00:00:00 | 2021-05-15 00:00:00 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly with a 'close' date range, so this answer won't exactly match the output you listed in the question.

For demo purposes I've made a csv file called `data.csv` with the data in your question

```
A,B,Start,End,Timestamp
A1,B1,2021-05-10 00:00:00,2021-05-27 00:00:00,2021-05-15 00:00:00
A1,B1,2021-05-12 00:00:00,2021-05-30 00:00:00,2021-04-15 00:00:00
A1,B1,2021-05-10 00:00:00,2021-05-12 00:00:00,2021-03-15 00:00:00
A1,B2,2021-06-02 00:00:00,2021-06-04 00:00:00,2021-02-15 00:00:00
A2,B3,2021-01-01 00:00:00,2022-01-01 00:00:00,2021-05-15 00:00:00
A2,B3,2021-07-15 00:00:00,2021-08-15 00:00:00,2021-04-15 00:00:00
A2,B4,2021-05-30 00:00:00,2021-06-15 00:00:00,2021-05-15 00:00:00
A2,B4,2021-06-02 00:00:00,2021-06-17 00:00:00,2021-04-15 00:00:00
```

An approach could be to compare the time differences for every group in the `B` column. We'll start with a group you mentioned in your question, i.e. where the `B` column value equals `"B1"`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

dff = df[df["B"] == "B1"]

>>> dff
    A   B  ...                  End            Timestamp
0  A1  B1  ...  2021-05-27 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00
1  A1  B1  ...  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-04-15 00:00:00
2  A1  B1  ...  2021-05-12 00:00:00  2021-03-15 00:00:00

# Difference in number of days between start and end date
>>> (pd.to_datetime(dff.End) - pd.to_datetime(dff.Start)).dt.days
0    17
1    18
2     2
dtype: int64

# How does each time difference compare to the time difference in the first row
>>> (pd.to_datetime(dff.End) - pd.to_datetime(dff.Start)).dt.days.diff().fillna(0)
0     0.0
1     1.0
2   -16.0
dtype: float64

# Filter where the number of days difference compared to the first row is less than 7 
>>> abs((pd.to_datetime(dff.End) - pd.to_datetime(dff.Start)).dt.days.diff().fillna(0)) < 7
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

# Filter dff based on earlier condition
>>> dff[abs((pd.to_datetime(dff.End) - pd.to_datetime(dff.Start)).dt.days.diff().fillna(0)) < 7]
    A   B                Start                  End            Timestamp
0  A1  B1  2021-05-10 00:00:00  2021-05-27 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00
1  A1  B1  2021-05-12 00:00:00  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-04-15 00:00:00
```

Above we've only compared one group of the `B` column. To do what we've done above for all groups, we could use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the `B` column. Then we could iterate through each group and filter each group using the filter mentioned earlier. After filtering all groups  these filtered groups can be contained inside a list and concatenated together.

```
df = pd.concat([
    group[
        abs(
            (pd.to_datetime(group.End) - pd.to_datetime(group.Start))
            .dt.days.diff()
            .fillna(0)
        )
        < 7
    ]
    for name, group in df.groupby("B")
])

>>> df
    A   B                Start                  End            Timestamp
0  A1  B1  2021-05-10 00:00:00  2021-05-27 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00
1  A1  B1  2021-05-12 00:00:00  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-04-15 00:00:00
3  A1  B2  2021-06-02 00:00:00  2021-06-04 00:00:00  2021-02-15 00:00:00
4  A2  B3  2021-01-01 00:00:00  2022-01-01 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00
6  A2  B4  2021-05-30 00:00:00  2021-06-15 00:00:00  2021-05-15 00:00:00
7  A2  B4  2021-06-02 00:00:00  2021-06-17 00:00:00  2021-04-15 00:00:00
```

Adjust the degree of closeness according to your needs. I've used days here as a measurement, but you could use a different one. You could use seconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, etc... Look through the [`Series` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html) for more examples.

Comment: When I was referring to close ranges,for example. A B Start End Timestamp
A1 B1 2021-05-10 -> 2021-05-27  2021-05-15 
A1 B1 2021-05-12 -> 2021-05-30  2021-04-15 

One can be considered to be the actualization of the other. However, in this other case:

A2 B3 2021-07-15 -> 2021-08-15  2021-04-15 
A2 B4 2021-05-30 -> 2021-06-15  2021-05-15

It can be seen that they are two very different time intervals since they do not share a beginning or an end and they are intervals in different months. Thank you very much for your answer!!